# What is the second argument in Rails' dynamic finders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The [devise_invitable gem](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) has this code:

```
find_by_invitation_token(params[:invitation_token], true)
```

Whas is the `true` argument? Very hard to google for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method definition can be found [here](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/590990d5a6d67673e12be149ed5d3fa9f1913365/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb#L280).

Note that it is not a Rails *dynamic finder* (although it looks like one), it is a custom method defined in the gem.

Answer (score 2):

Although it looks like a regular dynamic finder, that's actually a [custom method](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/590990d5a6d67673e12be149ed5d3fa9f1913365/lib/devise_invitable/model.rb#L280-L287).